# InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'PassengerViewModel' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

So i am trying to make my MVC website to use ViewModels instead of the data directly.

As the title says i am getting an exception and this is happening after i press the create button to add new data.

Ill list the snippets of codes that i am using right now.

This is the create operation in the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Surname,FirstName,Email")] PassengerViewModel passenger)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(passenger);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(passenger);
}
```

The Create page is a normal create page that visual studio created for me. the only change i made to it is instead of using the model data. the model is referring to my ViewModel.

Then in the migration class. the code is this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Passengers",
                schema: "WebSite",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Surname = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Passengers", x => x.Id);
                });
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of the entity, copy model values over, then add it (the entity) to the `DbContext`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Surname,FirstName,Email")] PassengerViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            Email = model.Email
        };
        await _context.Passengers.AddAsync(passenger);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(passenger);
}
```